Does it make sense to say to a person "you're good to go" when he is done with something?
In the dictionary

be good to go
​(of a thing) to be prepared and ready for use; (of a person) to be
prepared and ready to do something
By tomorrow afternoon the document will be good to go.
I’ve spent several months training for this race so now I’m good to
go.

Now, I am teaching my daughter math and she has just finished the last math question. Now she can play or do whatever she wants.
Can I say to her "you're good to go" when she is done with her math lesson?

I have heard people use "you're good to go" in this sense in everyday language in Australia. Often in contexts where you might need to finalise something before the interaction is done e.g. after a visit to the doctor where you might ask the receptionist there is anything left to do or any payment to make after the visit and they tell you that "you're good to go."

@JayBee, I had been living in Australia for 12 years. I felt like I learned from them. The sentence just popped out of my mouth unconsciously.

That's fine.  It's a typical casual expression so I don't want to over-analyse.
It means that she isn't prepared or ready to go play until she has finished her maths lesson -  that finishing maths is necessary before playtime.  Perhaps that is the implication you want to give.
It might be more normal if there is a clearer link between what you are doing and the next activity.  "You've got your coat and boots on, so you are good to go and play in the snow"
